# Likert data analysis and statistical tests

Tags: likert

I have likert data from 657 respondents where i have asked them to rate whether a condition has affected their career progression. I have 6 different conditions and they can have up to 4 of them. I would like to know if there is a significant difference between the likert scores for each of the conditions and also if the number of co-occuring conditions affects career progression. It has been a while since I have done any meaningful statistical analysis and my research has me very confused. What tests should i use please. Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

I would start with ordinal logistic regression, with  the Likert score as the dependent variable and the conditions as independent variables and also number of conditions.  You might want to do this as two separate analyses.

One issue with the first is that it might be combinations of conditions that are most important, but with each person having up to 4 out of 6, there will be too many combinations to look at them all.